# JSP and FormBean with no Setter

Tags: jsp, javabeans

Would having JSP code set a property that doesnt exist in the FormBean anymore (ie no private variable and no publig getter/setter) cause any problems, granted that that field is not referenced anywhere else?

Comment: Try it, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Its a rather large application that Im working in. Im getting a general execption and Im trying to narrow down where the problem is...

Comment: So, with the source of the application, the stack trace of the exception, the ability to debug, you have problems narrowing it down, but we, without anything except a vague description, should be able to do it?

Comment: I thought it was a relatively general question...

Comment: That's the problem. It's much too general and vague. Ypu didn't post any code, and you could find the answer yourself by simply executing that code.